# Redirect to other than App url

Tags: redirect, meteor, iron-router

I'm currently working on e-commerce based website for our country.I need to integrate a local payment gateway solution. The architecture of that system is actually to based on REST. so I need to `post` several data to a specific `url` and they `response` back with a `content` of another `url` where my app should be redirected. After the transaction either success/failed/canceled, the third party system redirects back to my app url.

now I'm having problem with redirecting to the third-party `url` from my app.

```
var result =  HTTP.post(url,{params:data_me});
console.log(result.content+' ....');
```

The `post` method is synchronous and i recieve the url properly. how do I now redirect my app to their response url.
Note: these statements are written in a server method. And I'm using iron router for my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're doing the integration on the server, have the server method return the new `url` to the client. Then on the client simply do:

```
 window.location=url;
```

iron-router won't take you to an offsite url because it only manages internal routes.

[docs](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)

Comment: it's not working. after putting the statement in the client my url becomes : `http://localhost:3000/%22http://sandbox.easypayway.com/payment/paynow.php?track=DRE*****713%22`. star marks are for illustration.

Comment: sorry my bad! response was given with double quotes, removing that solves the problem.

Comment: please revert back to last answer , i'll mark it as correct. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `location.href` in client **side** code, better put it under `onRendered`

```
location.href="http://example.com"
```

or use `iron-router`'s Router to write redirect header in **server** side

```
Router.route('/myurl', function () {
  //do sth
  var url = "http://example.com"

  this.response.writeHead(302, {
    'Location': url
  });

  this.response.end();

}, {
  where: 'server'
});
```